# How to keep original format when replacing bookmark in docx file using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a docx template that need to replace all bookmarks when generating real document. But I am facing format inconsistent problem.

```
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
            CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
            List<CTBookmark> bookmarks = ctp.getBookmarkStartList();
            for (CTBookmark bookmark : bookmarks) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : bookMarkValuesMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (bookmark.getName().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
                        run.setText(entry.getValue());
                        ctp.getDomNode().insertBefore(run.getCTR().getDomNode(), bookmark.getDomNode());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my code that will go through each paragraph and find if there are any bookmarks. if yes, try to match with the bookmark value map and set the data into bookmark.

After generated the document. The format is different.

eg. if my template originally need to insert bookmark value with font size 10. But the outcome is bookmark value with font size 12 appending to template text with font size 10.

Any idea to my situation? Thanks

Comment: A new run will get new formatting. Can you re-use an existing run that is styled how you already want it to look?

Comment: Could you teach me how to get bookmark’s run? I can’t find any methods like bookmark.getCtr().getRun(). Many thanks

Comment: Simplest thing is probably to look at the underlying XML, then go from there. Rename the `.docx` file to `.zip`, unpack, look at the `document.xml` file and search for your bookmark to see how word needs it all encoding